# lansdcape - is there a clustered solution

Tags: landscape

I realise that using juju it states there's a fully redundant 'on premis' installation  - if I have read this right, this only puts the services onto seperate servers. What I would like is a fully clustered / failover type landscape 'on premis' service, does anyone know  if this possible in landscape - or do I need to resort to failover software.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the [landscape-scalable juju bundle](https://jujucharms.com/landscape-scalable/), you are correct, as the configuration is to have units spread on different machines. However, the services used in this bundle (postgresql, rabbitmq-server, haproxy, landscape-server) support clustering to some extent. Depending on your needs and the load, you can call `juju add-unit <service-name>` to effectively cluster and/or scale some of those services and have fallbacks.

I suggest you also check the documentation of those individual juju charms  ([rabbit](https://jujucharms.com/rabbitmq-server/), [haproxy](https://jujucharms.com/haproxy/xenial/41), [postgres](https://jujucharms.com/postgresql/xenial/101)), as those charms have a few options related to clustering/fallbacks,